# How should we tag Prince of Persia?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warrior-within) tag was just created, and used in conjunction with the [prince-of-persia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia) tag.  While the Warrior Within "subtitle" is unique to my knowledge, and fairly well-known, do we have a general rule for this?  Obviously [prince-of-persia-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-warrior-within) is too long, but what about [pop-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-warrior-within)?  (PoP is a well known acronym among my gamer friends, not sure if it's well known enough.)

Should we always use the main title in conjunction with the subtitle (whether in two tags or in one)?  Are there rules for making short forms?

Comment: [tag:prince-of-persia-4] or whatever number it is?

Comment: I suppose not.  At any rate, it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "pop" is common enough so that [pop-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-warrior-within) will be clear and obvious - especially if the tag wiki excerpt (displayed on mouse-hover) shows the full name.

Comment: On the other hand, we tag "The Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion" as both "The Elder Scrolls" and "Oblivion" (in the same way we might tag "Pokemon 4th gen" and "Pokemon Pearl"). I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but it is the precedent. (And what stopped me from creating this meta-thread myself). Personally, I think "pop" on its own does not seem sufficiently relatable as acronyms go.

Comment: @Raven It's a good point. Considering that taglines are probably more unique than game names anyway, maybe it actually is the best to use two different tags - one for series and one for specific game.

Comment: But we use `assasins-creed-bh` for Assassin's Creed Brotherhood, and I'd been advised in chat to use `kingdom-hearts-bbs` for Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep under the logic that if someone starts typing it in, they'll see the name with the acronym for the subtitle rather than vice versa. So using that, I'd recommend `prince-of-persia-ww` but then I see we also have `dk-country-returns` for Donkey Kong Country Returns, so now I have no idea *what* to do.

Comment: @Matthew - nor likely to be implemented. Jeff and co are quite determined to not increase tag length for a multitude of reasons. I'd say "series by series" basis though.

Answer (score 2):

**The tag name is now [prince-of-persia-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-warrior-within).**

Since the maximum tag length was [increased to 35 characters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've went ahead and retagged questions about the Prince of Persia series to use the full title whenever possible.

- [pop-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-warrior-within) → [prince-of-persia-warrior-within](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-warrior-within)
- [pop-the-forgotten-sands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-the-forgotten-sands) → [prince-of-persia-forgotten-sands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-forgotten-sands)
- [pop-the-two-thrones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pop-the-two-thrones) → [prince-of-persia-the-two-thrones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-the-two-thrones)
- [prince-of-persia-08](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-08) → [prince-of-persia-2008](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-2008)

Other games in the series were already using their official titles.

- [prince-of-persia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia)
- [prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prince-of-persia-the-sands-of-time)

Comment: price-of-persia-08 should probably be made a synonym of prince-of-persia-2008, since prince-of-persia-08 contains the tag information

Comment: @Wondercricket I've already gone ahead and made a [suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/241343) to re-add the tag information.

Comment: Excellent. I hadn't checked the review queues today, so I didn't see it